# Get last object of ManytoMany connected table in Django

Tags: django

I have a Django model like the following:

```
class RFIDInventorySerials(models.Model):
    serial = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, default=0)
    coordinate = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, default=0)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)


class RFIDInventory(models.Model):
    reference_number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    serials = models.ManyToManyField(RFIDInventorySerials)
```

and a list of `serial` such as :

```
s = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

for every `serial` I want to get the last `time_stamp`. How can I do that ?

I did:

```
last_seen = []

        for i, v in df_hr1['Miss'].iteritems():
            last = RFIDInventorySerials.objects.filter(serial=v).last()
            print("last", last)
            last_seen.append(last.start)
```

But if the list becomes longer then the loop won't be a solution to this

Answer (score 0):

try something like this;

```
serials_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
# suppose you have a list of serials and want to filter last seen serials
required_result = RFIDInventorySerials.objects.filter(
    serial__in=serials_list
).order_by('-timestamp').distinct('serial')
```

I don't have any validation mechanism so it may or may not work but the idea is first order by timestamp and select distinct serial